# Whats the URL from the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Today I installed the Microsoft Dynamics CRM on my Windows Server 2008 r2.

Everything was fine, but now I can't find the Link to my Hompage.

Can somebody of you tell me the default URL from the Microsoft Dynamics CRM? I just installed the 90 day free Trial version of it.

When I type in my browser: `http://localhost/` then I get the Error:

> HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
>
> You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.
>
> and here are some Informations about my Server:
>
> Detailed Error Information
>
> Module IIS Web Core
>
> Notification AuthenticateRequest
>
> Handler StaticFile
>
> Error Code 0x80070005
>
> Requested URL `http://localhost:80/`
>
> Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot
>
> Logon Method Not yet determined
>
> Logon User Not yet determined

How can I fix that?

If it would be fine, I think, I could enter the URL in my webbrowser and the typical page from the CRM comes?

I use Internet Explorer. And I already have the Administrator rights on my Server.

EDIT: Ok, the Problem with Localhost changed. When I type in Localhost now, i came to the IIS website. But that doesn't helped me a lot. So, what I've done was: I added the `Windows authentication` to the Server Role from the IIS Server. I found it in the Security part.

But the problem with the URL from CRM is already here.

EDIT EDIT: I found out, that I have the Port 5555 for the CRM. So, when I write in the Internet Explorer: `http://localhost:5555/` then appears a very long and complex Error.

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Caller does not have enough privilege to set CallerOriginToken to the specified value. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Caller does not have enough privilege to set CallerOriginToken to the specified value.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[CrmException: Caller does not have enough privilege to set CallerOriginToken to the specified value.]
   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ExternalMessageDispatcher.VerifyCallerOrigin(ExecutionContext context) +260
   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ExternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(String messageName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, PropertyBag fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId) +724
   Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.RequestBase.Process(Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId) +149
   Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.RequestBase.Process(CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId) +183
   Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.CrmServiceInternal.Execute(RequestBase request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId) +465
   Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.InProcessCrmService.Execute(Object request) +2688
   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.PlatformCommand.ExecuteInternal() +368
   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.DataSource.RetrieveAvailableLanguages() +40
   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Utility.ApplicationLanguage.get_AvailableLanguages() +220
   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppUIPage.get_AvailableLanguages() +9
   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AnonymousPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) +25
   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Web.Pages.ErrorHandlerPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) +211
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +143
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1477




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

EDIT: Now it works finaly. The Problem was, that my Account wasn't in the Privacy User Group. I found it on this very helpful blog:

[Link 1](http://support.cryptzone.com/cryptzone/topics/i_receive_the_error_mmc_could_not_create_the_snap_in_on_my_my_win2008_server/)
[Link 2](http://mscrm4humans.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/microsoft-crm-crmexception-caller-does-not-have-enough-privilege-to-set-callerorigintoken-to-the-specified-value/)
[Link 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonasd/archive/2008/01/11/caller-does-not-have-enough-privilege-to-set-callerorigintoken-to-the-specified-value.aspx/)

Sorry, I can't post more than 1 link. So I had to do it in Code. Hope this helps somebody who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to register the CRM server on a different port (we use 5555 for instance), especially if it's for development and not not to be exposed to a customer.

And to answer your question. The address is as follows. Suppose that you've registered two organizations: *monkey* and *donkey*.

```
http://localhost:5555/monkey  
http://localhost:5555/donkey
```

And the discovery etc. services are as follows (for *monkey* on default port).

```
http://localhost:80/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc  
http://localhost:80/CRM-Konsulterna/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc  
http://localhost:80/CRM-Konsulterna/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc
```

You need to keep in mind two things (which you probably know of already).
1. Port 80 doesn't need to be specified explicitly, nor does the protocol.
2. *Localhost* will only work if you're in fact on the server (otherwise, specify the IP).

Comment: It's just a Test. We use the Free Trial. Later we will buy the whole CRM maybe. But now it works finally. I posted the links, wich helped  me into my post at the bottom :)

Comment: I fixed the links for you. It looks better now.

Answer (score 2):

The url is nice, check if you have another application in port 80. Try set windows authentication in iis, see [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Verify also the access to AD.

Comment: How can I check, if there's another application on port 80?

Comment: Check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonasd/archive/2008/01/11/caller-does-not-have-enough-privilege-to-set-callerorigintoken-to-the-specified-value.aspx)